# Semantic difference between function return and assignment

Tags: c, return, language-lawyer

The Standard provides an example at 6.8.6.4:

> EXAMPLE In:
>
> ```
> struct s { double i; } f(void);
> union {
>     struct {
>         int f1;
>         struct s f2;
>     } u1;
>     struct {
>         struct s f3;
>         int f4;
>     } u2;
> } g;
> struct s f(void)
> {
>     return g.u1.f2;
> }
> /* ... */
> g.u2.f3 = f();
> ```
>
> there is no undefined behavior, although there would be if the
> assignment were done directly (without using a function call to fetch
> the value).

Could you explain why there would be UB in case of direct assignment. It seems a contradiction to what was defined above the example in the Standard:

> If the expression has a type different from the return type of the
> function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by
> assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

So the semantic of `return` and assignments should be the same.

Comment: Did you see the foot note #175 that mentions the difference concerning overlapping (6.5.16.1 §3)? "_The return statement is not an assignment._" I didn't search the standard, but isn't there somewhere defined that function return values are temporary objects?

Comment: @thebusybee: Temporary objects are defined only for returns of structures containing arrays. (Because you need an object in case the array is referenced, since it must be converted to a pointer, as in `f().array[3]`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil So an aggresively optimizing compiler might inline the function and compile an assignment? Hm, sounds like an interesting experiment, and to compare this to compilations of explicit assignments.

Comment: @thebusybee Sure I saw, but footnotes are not normative...

Comment: But they explain text. ;-) In this case it led to the answer you wanted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A quick test with GCC (MinGW 8.1.0) revealed that assignments and inlined function calls produce the same code. However, other options or compilers might behave differently.

Comment: @thebusybee An interesting point about this example is that if a compiler optimizes a function call like this into an assignment, then the compiler will have to handle the case of "non-exactly overlapping" objects.

Comment: @thebusybee: Inline a function does not just behave as if the source code were rewritten with the function source code in place of the call. Inlining, and other optimization, must maintain the original semantics.

Comment: _Sure I saw, but footnotes are not normative_ Neither examples are, so just ignore this one.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know, I am just tinkering, not presuming  anything. The simple example apparently generates the same assembly because it does not violate the semantics. Actually all reading is done before the writing. -- "Unfortunately" I'll have some days off, including being non-digital, so that I cannot run other experiments in the near future. I'd love to see how GCC handles such UB cases. (I am well aware that a specific compiler implementation does not prove anything, especially when it comes to corner cases of the standard.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is not about conversion. In the example, the value in the return statement has the same type as the function return type, so no conversion is needed.

The key point is the requirement (standard clause 6.5.16.1, paragraph 3) that assignment is only defined for overlapping objects if the overlap is exact:

> If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way
> the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall
> have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.

Hence the assignment:

```
g.u2.f3 = g.u1.f2;
```

would be undefined behavior (since the objects are "non-exactly overlapping"), but in the example the assignment happens via a function call so the assignment is not directly between non-exactly overlapping objects and thus not undefined behavior.

Comment: Nice point, thanks.